# dirtree Template Formatting Changed

Tags: dirtree

I've integrated `dirtree` package into a LaTeX document I am working on, but it appears to be interfering with the document format (see image here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmWns.png)). How do I tell LaTeX to maintain original formatting after `dirtree`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

This is just a test.

\begin{itemize}
 \item This is a test 1
 \item This is a test 2
 \item This is a test 3
\end{itemize}

\dirtree{%
.1 \framebox{\textbf{NDLTD}}. 
.2 GATECH. 
.2 \framebox{\textbf{OCLC}}. 
.3 OCLCNo--477262203.metadata. 
}

\begin{itemize}
 \item This is a test 1
 \item This is a test 2
 \item This is a test 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update #1**
I just discovered, while preparing a minimum working example, that the problem is as a result of loading the parskip package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In my machine, I don't get a crammed output as you did.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Thank you for this. Please see update #1 in original post. I believe the problem is as a result of using `parskip` package with `parfill` option.

Comment: In version `0.2` try enclosing `\dirtree{}` with braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like a problem with an old version of `parskip` or `dirtree`because I cannot see any problem. Put `\listfiles` into your preamble and compare the list which is at the end of the log file:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 dirtree.sty    2012/12/11 v0.32 package wrapper for dirtree
 dirtree.tex    2012/12/11 v0.32 `dirtree' (jcc)
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
  omscmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

[image]

Comment: As it turns out, it appears I am using an older version of dirtree --I have v0.2 (2006/01/25); I see you have v0.32.

Comment: then update it. On the CTAN is the latest version or run your update manager